# Como resolver o erro: "Whoops! There was an error." Podem me ajudar?

Tags: php, laravel

Olá estou desenvolvendo minha primeira aplicação utilizando o framework laravel e obtive um problema no momento de fazer logout. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto é o que ele me devolve. Se alguem tiver enfrentado problemas parecido por favor me dê um retorno. Desde já agradeço.
Estou utilizando a versão 5.7.15 do Laravel

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedException`.. verifica o método HTTP que está sendo usado e se as rotas permitem ele. Exemplo, você está acessando `pagina.com/logout` por GET, mas as rotas só permitem por POST.

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu o meu problema.